# Sharing contact number in Email

Tags: grammar, email

I would like to share my Mobile number with Client through email. The same number is my WhatsApp number.
Please help me to correct the below sentence to write with correct grammar and as well as a polite 
sentence to convey the message.

'Please find my contact number (+XXX) XXX-XXX-XXXX, which is the same number for WhatsApp. Please feel free to reach at any time.'

Comment: You might drop the "Please find" when it's just the tag at the bottom of an email. And also you might drop the "Please feel free to reach at any time."

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @puppetsock to remove the "Please find". Using "please" is polite, which is good in formal, professional communication. However, "find" is not the right verb to use.

Starting with "My contact number is (contact number here)..." is perfectly acceptable.

If you do want more of a lead-in, "Here is my contact number: (contact number here)...." is also grammatical.

If you prefer to keep the "please" somewhere, then I would recommend keeping the phrase "Please feel free to reach **me** at anytime." This phrase is very polite, and indicates a welcoming attitude from you, and directed to your client. Note that I added the pronoun "me". This is added, because you need to specify **who** is being communicated with in the grammar (even though it is obvious from other context-clues).